# Angularjs material design md-tab : validate before changing the tab

Tags: angular, angular-material

How can call a validate function and change the md-tab only if the validate function return true.

Answer (score 0):

For the case that your tabs are working with routing ... each tab have a different route. You can use Guards to validate before changing the tab.

Guards Info: https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards

guards are kind of interceptors and this is an example of a guard I use for authentication hope it helps.

```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
  import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
  import {AuthService} from '../services/auth.service'
  @Injectable()
  export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private authservice: AuthService, private router: Router) {
    }

    canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
      if (this.authservice.isAuthenticated()){
        return true;
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['auth/signIn'], {});

      }
    }

  }
```

Comment: I do want in angular 1.5